# Android Java String operations not working

Tags: java, android, string, replace, contains

I've the problem that all string operations doesn't seem to work:

```
String received_message = new String(lmessage, 0, packet.getLength());
```

Note: received_message is "start.hello.end"

```
if (received_message.startsWith("start.") && received_message.endsWith(".end"))
{
    result = 1;
}

received_message = received_message.replace("start.", "");
received_message = received_message.replace(".end", "");
```

Result:

result is 0, received_message is still "start.hello.end"

--

But this is working correctly:

```
if (received_message.startsWith("s") && received_message.endsWith("d"))
{
    result = 1;
}

received_message = received_message.replace("s", "");
received_message = received_message.replace(".", "");
```

It's just working if I make this functions with a single Char.

How can I get it working for whole Strings?

Comment: if you change it to received_message.indexOf(".start") != -1 && received_message.indexOf(".end")  != -1) it works?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Also the replace function doesn't replace anything.

Comment: Just a few pointers: don't use the platform default character set when constructing the string, use soomething like: `new String(lmessage, 0, packet.getLength(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`

Comment: You may have some corrupted/invisible character somewhere in your string, try with successively more and more characters to see where it fails.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the encoding. The Windows server used Unicode, the Android system used UTF-16 as standard. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the encoding. The Windows server used Unicode, the Android system used UTF-16 as standard. So the String contained some invisible characters..